# Change order of main query according to Eloquent WhereHas Relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, geolocation, eloquent-relationship

```
$collection = USER::whereHas('userLocations', function ($query) use ($filterId) {
      $query->select(DB::raw('*, ( 6367 * acos( cos( radians('.$filterId['lat'].') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians('.$filterId['lng'].') ) + sin( radians('.$filterId['lat'].') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance'))
       ->having('distance', '<', 10)
       ->orderBy('distance);
    });
$collection = $collection->paginate(config('p.number_of_rows'));
return $collection;
```

I am trying to display user whose location range is from near to far. The orderBy doesn't seem to work. The user collection should be in the order of ascending distance.

Any advice would be appreciated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orderby in your query is using just for nested select. You should use join, if you wanna order by distance parameter. Try something like this:

UPD:

```
$raw =  '( 6367 * acos( cos( radians(' . $filterId['lat'] . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $filterId['lng'] . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $filterId['lat'] . ') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )';
$collection = USER::select('users.*', DB::raw($raw . 'as distance'))
        ->join('userLocations', 'userLocations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->having(DB::raw($raw), '<', 10)
        ->orderBy($raw);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I am getting unknown column distance error.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Try to order by your calculated value: orderBy(DB::raw('( 6367 * acos( cos( radians(' . $filterId['lat'] . ') ) * cos( radians( latitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $filterId['lng'] . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $filterId['lat'] . ') ) * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) )'))
(Put this raw in variable for double use:)

Comment: ->join('user_locations', 'user_locations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
->having($qu, '<', 10)
->orderBy($qu);
where $qu is the raw you provided but now i am getting Unknown column 'latitude' in 'having clause'

Comment: Try change to: ->join('user_locations', 'user_locations.user_id', '=', 'users.id') ->having(DB::raw($raw), '<', 10) ->orderBy(DB::raw($raw));

Comment: getting the same error.. Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'latitude' in 'having clause'. :(

Comment: changing having to where and ->orderBy(DB::raw($raw)) worked :)